# Como bloquear um formulário depois de certo tempo de inatividade?

Tags: c#

Exemplo: Depois de 1 minuto de inatividade o formulário 'sistema' se desabilita e chama um formulário de 'login', após concluir o login ele retorna ao formulário 'sistema' e ativa ele novamente..

Ou pode ser ao apertar um botão ele bloqueia o formulário 'sistema' e chama o 'login', quando efetuar o login ele ativa o formulário novamente..

Tentei desabilitando o `this.Enabled` do formulário atual após clicar no botão de bloqueio e depois disso criando uma instância do 'login' e abrindo ele, na lógica o comando para desbloquear o formulário 'sistema' seria ao clicar no botão de login, depois das verificações de nome e senha, mas não consigo acessar a propriedade `.Enabled` do formulário 'sistema' pelo 'login'.. Já tentei criar uma variável estática para controlar isso, mas não funciona pelo fato de não ter uma função Update que atualiza a cada segundo (como no Unity) e não sei criar essa função no Visual Studio

Comment: Pode compartilhar a estrutura dos códigos? Já tentou *[Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx)*?

Comment: tente `IEnumerator` acho que deve funcionar.[Exemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Consegui aqui, porém ele registra apenas clique ou modificação dos campos como atividade, movimento de mouse é descartado, ou seja se o usuário ficar só movendo o mouse no formulário, quando atingir o time ele vai bloquear.. Vou postar o código que usei aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja resetar seu `iddle time` (ou seja, seu `Timer`) no movimento do mouse ou no teclar do botão, considere:

**`Form1.cs`**

```
    public Point mouseLocation;
    public static LoginBloq nvLoginBloq = new LoginBloq(); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.KeyPress += _keyPress;
        this.MouseMove += _mouseMove;
    }

    private void _mouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseLocation = e.Location;
        this.ResetaIddleTimer();
    }

    private  void _keyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ResetaIddleTimer();
    }

    void ResetaIddleTimer()
    {
        // código para resetar o iddle time
    }
```

Observe que `LoginBloq` é criado uma única vez em `Form1.cs` e é `static`. De acordo com o fluxo do seu código, você pode controlar a visibilidade de `nvLoginBloq` de qualquer outro form:

**`OutroForm.cs`**

```
public partial class OutroForm : Form
{
    public OutroForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Form1.nvLoginBloq.Visible = true;

    }
}
```

Ou seja, desta maneira você **centraliza** o controle do `iddle time` e ao mesmo tempo o acesso ao `LoginBloq` numa classe só (`Form1`).

Comment: Funcionou, só não deu pra criar a instancia como public static, pois estava dando conflito.. É assim, uma tela de splash abre instancia de login, essa instancia abre outra instancia 'interface' na hora que se inicia (pois preciso que ela seja public static, para bloquear e desbloquear).. daí o visual nao permite criar outra instancia publica e estatica ao iniciar de outro formulário.. Então criei uma instancia como estava mesmo.. Funcionou de boa capturar o movimento do mouse

Comment: Tem como eu 'destruir' a instancia? Tipo, depois que ele autenticar o login  no nvLoginBloq, tem como destruir esse nvLoginBloq? assim apagando ela e não ir criando instancia após instancia

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho, que bom que funcionou. `static` não permite criar outras instâncias mesmo, esta é a vantagem, é uma instância global que permite somente alterar as propriedades, etc. Quer uma dica? Crie um método `public static Init() {}` no seu `Form1.cs` e dentro dele sete tudo o que precisar, inclusive a primeira e única instancia de `LoginBloq`! Quem deve chamar ela? O seu `SplashScreen.cs: Form1.Init()`. Inclusive EU particularmente gero todos os forms uma vez só (ou Pages no caso do WPF) usando um método `static` no meu Form1 (ou MainWindow, no caso do WPF).

Comment: sim sim, tipo eu não criei outra instância do nvLogin e nem do nvInterface (que é são as duas instancias estática).. O IDE até compila, mas quando executa dá erro na instancia estática criada do nvLogin (ela está dento de uma instancia estática do nvFormulario que está dentro de uma instancia comum da tela de login principal)..Essas instâncias estáticas são criadas depois da tela de da criação da instancia do Login principal... Não entendi o erro da IDE '-'

Comment: Como você estaria criando essas instâncias, posso ver?

Comment: `Login nvLogin = new Login();` no form de Splash -- `public static Interface nvInterface = new Interface();` no form `nvLogin` (para poder controlar time e disponibilidade)  -- `LoginBloq nvLoginBloq = new LoginBloq();` no form `nvInteface`.. Desse jeito não dá erro, mas fica instanciando o `nvLoginBloq`, ao colocar `public static LoginBloq nvLoginBloq = new LoginBloq();` no form `nvInteface` ele dá o erro.. Mas consegui arrumar aqui, instanciando estaticamente o `nvLoginBloq` no `nvLogin` e alterando os códigos dos formulários (para limpar os texts box depois de autenticar o login etc )

Comment: Então deu certo? Bem, eu acho que pro seu propósito, o ideal mesmo é manter uma instância só de todos os forms! Mas fico contente que tenha conseguido!

Comment: Estou enfrentando um problema com seu código, ele só reseta o contador enquanto eu tiver clicando ou passando o mouse no `form` propriamente dito, se eu ficar passando o mouse no `menustrip` ou em algum painel, ele chama o form de `login` mesmo com o movimento do mouse, isso complica.

Comment: Opa! Isto é simples de se resolver. Se você manter os métodos `_mouseMove` e `_keyPress` publicos e estáticos no `Form1.cs`, então basta que em **cada form**  seu, você registre estes eventos. Ex.: `FormNovo.cs` (no construtor): `this.KeyPress += Form1._keyPress;
        this.MouseMove += Form1._mouseMove;`

Comment: O mais importante é **centralizar** TODAS as ações repetitivas no seu código, de repente, criar até uma classe estática só para isto (até recomendável), exemplo: `IddleState.cs`. De qualquer forma, Leonardo, CADA FORM SEU terá de registrar os eventos `this.KeyPress` e `this.MouseMove` e informar os métodos num lugar só (sim, pois imagina cada form tendo seus próprios métodos _keyPress e _mouseMove?)

Comment: Outro detalhe: O `Timer` precisa também estar num local só (e ser estático, recomendável), por exemplo, no `Form1.cs` para que TODOS compartilhem o mesmo contador e somente um seja resetado, etc.

Comment: Se a resposta foi válida, por favor, considere marcando-a!

Comment: Não deu nem alterando para publica e estática, o painel e menu está no mesmo formulário que esses eventos, exemplo, o código só funciona enquanto o mouse está na área que a seta entra em contato com o background do formulário principal, quando a seta enta em contato com outro objeto do formulario (como botão, painel, menu, imagem, etc) e tu fica movimentando o mouse lá nesses objetos o código não funciona, após um tempo o Login é chamado, mesmo com o mouse em movimento,, tentei tirando o `this.` mas continuou o erro

Comment: Cada formulário seu está com os eventos do mouse e teclado registrados? Onde está o contador (Timer)?

Answer (score 0):

Bom consegui, há apenas um inconveniente, ele não registra movimento do mouse como atividade, apenas clique, mudança de campos, etc..
O código é grande:

**Formulário 'sistema'**

```
public Timer relogio; // cria timer
public int contador = -1; // contador (conta o tempo em segundos)
public bool atv = false; // booleano para controle do formulario de login

// abaixo do InitializeComponent();
relogio = new Timer(); // cria uma instancia de time
relogio.Interval = 1000; //depermina o tempo (assim fica em segundos)
relogio.Enabled = true; // ativa o time
this.relogio.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.relogio_Tick); // cria um metodo de controle

private void Interface_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//redefine contador quando há clique no formulario (deve-se criar isso para cada campo de formulario, desde menu a campos de texto)
    contador = -1;
}

private void relogio_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //controlador de time
{
    if (contador == 10) // quando o contador chegar a 10 (10 segundos)
    {
        if (atv == false)//se a tela de login nao estiver em execução
        {
            this.Enabled = false;//desabilita o formulario 'sistema'
            LoginBloq nvLoginBloq = new LoginBloq(); //cria uma instancia do login
            nvLoginBloq.Show(); // abre a instancia
        }
        else{}//se atv = true (se formulario 'login' estiver ativo não faz nada)
    }

    else if(contador > 10) //se contador for mais que 10 (10 segundos)
    {
        this.relogio.Enabled = false;//desabilita relogio
    }
    contador++;// a cada vez ele que executa o metodo (sempre) ele aumenta contador
}
```

**Formulário 'login'**

```
//após o InitializeComponent();
Login.nvInterface.atv = true; // fala que esta ativo (para nao ficar criando novos form 'login')

// após ele permitir o login (ao clicar no botao de login)
this.Enabled = false; // desabilita a si mesmo
Login.nvInterface.atv = false; //
Login.nvInterface.contador = -1; //rededine o contador (em segundos)
Login.nvInterface.relogio.Enabled = true; //ativa o time novamente
Login.nvInterface.Show(); //mostra novamente o formulario 'sistema'
Login.nvInterface.Enabled = true; // ativa (desbloqueia) formulario 'sistema'
this.Visible = false; // torna-se invisivel
//as linhas Visible e Enabled, são necessárias nessa ordem, se não ele buga
```

*Login.nvInterface* - é uma instancia criada em outro formulário Login (o principal), para exibir o formulário 'sistema'

Se tiver algum formulário antes do 'sistema' (como é esse caso)

**Formulário anterior**

```
// antes de tudo
public static Interface nvInterface = new Interface(); //criar uma instancia publica do formulario 'sistema'

// depois de InitializeComponent();
nvInterface.relogio.Enabled = false; //desativa relogio do formulario 'sistema'

// no metodo do botão que vai para o formulario 'sistema' ou depois do InitializeComponent(); do formulario 'sistema'
nvInterface.relogio.Enabled = true; //ativa relogio do formulario 'sistema'

// assim ele 'trava' o time da instancia ate que ela seja exibida
```

Comment: `LoginBloq` é instanciado toda vez? Eu faria isto uma vez só no form principal e controlaria somente a visibilidade, @Leonardo VIlarinho

Comment: Sim é instanciado toda vez que a tela 'bloqueia' ou o user clica no botão de bloqueio.. Eu pensei que ele substituiria o que está instanciado atualmente, por criar um com o mesmo nome, sou novato nisso ainda.. Mas se eu instanciar só um e controlar a visibilidade, alguma hora não daria algum bug (pois ele pega informações de arquivos e compara com o que o usuário digitou)?

Comment: Opa! Não daria bug não, pois a função do `static` é esta mesma! Elementos não estáticos são elementos "novos" (com a keyword `new`),  e não elementos que se mantém os mesmos. A vantagem é que mantendo um `LoginBloq nvLoginBloq` no form principal, é possível pegá-la de qualquer outro form e ainda por cima não necessitar de novo instanciamento. Se sua aplicação ainda tiver o foco em `UI` com elementos visuais, efeitos, etc, considere usar `WPF`, eu adoro WPF. É o C# mais "visual".

Comment: Uma vez tive que trabalhar com o mesmo objetivo que o seu: `iddle time`. Fiz um contador da mesma forma que você. Como era uma aplicação para totem (aqueles PC de auto atendimento) o `iddle time` era resetado só quando o usuário fazia algo (tocava num botão, por exemplo). No seu caso, se você precisa verificar se o mouse foi movimentado, veja minha resposta abaixo.

Comment: Nunca tinha visto esse WPF (o desing criei só mudando as propriedades no Visual Studio) até que ficou legal, só queria transparência no fundo (o que não deu pra fazer)

Comment: Opa, dá sim, você pode usar um background com opacity! É quase um CSS. Mas não podemos estender outras conversas aqui, é contra o regulamento hehe abraço!